# problem to install library in anaconda pront

Tags: python, anaconda

i proved to install ddt library but appeears this error: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
How can I solve this problem?

maybe the I had the doubt that when I installed anaconda distribution for Windows I didn't choose "Only for me"

Comment: Have you tried installing with admin privileges?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.